# How can I change the textual representation displayed for a type in Swift?

Tags: swift

How can I modify the textual output that gets displayed in string interpolation?

The `Printable` protocol looks the most obvious but it's ignored in both String Interpolation and when printing the instance, e.g:

```
struct Point : Printable
{
    var x = 0
    var y = 0

    var description : String {
        return "(\(x), \(y))"
    }

    func toString() -> String {
        return description
    }
}
```

Likewise the `toString()` convention has no effect either:

```
var p = Point(x: 10, y: 20)

println(p)                   // V11lldb_expr_05Point (has 2 children)
println("\(p)")              // V11lldb_expr_05Point (has 2 children)
println(p.description)       // (10, 20)
println("\(p.description)")  // (10, 20)
```

The behavior is different again in PlayGround which uses its own String representation for structs, i.e:

```
p // {x 10, y 20}
```

Is there a way I can change how an instance is displayed?

Comment: The above code works as would be expected in Playgrounds in Xcode 6.3 beta 4

Answer (score 138, accepted):

### Swift 2 - 4

#### Summary

Conform to the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol and add `description`:

```
var description: String {
    return "description here"
}
```

---

#### Example

You can create some structs:

```
struct Animal : CustomStringConvertible {
    let type : String

    var description: String {
        return type
    }
}

struct Farm : CustomStringConvertible {
    let name : String
    let animals : [Animal]

    var description: String {
        return "\(name) is a \(self.dynamicType) with \(animals.count) animal(s)."
    }
}
```

If you initialize them:

```
let oldMajor = Animal(type: "Pig")
let boxer = Animal(type: "Horse")
let muriel = Animal(type: "Goat")

let orwellsFarm = Farm(name: "Animal Farm", animals: [oldMajor, boxer, muriel])
```

The custom descriptions will appear in your playground:

[image]

See also `CustomDebugStringConvertible`, which you can use for more verbose output during debugging.

---

#### Usage Note

You can initialize a `String` from any type *without* implementing this protocol. For example:

[image]

For this reason, the docs say:

> Using `CustomStringConvertible` as a generic constraint, or accessing a conforming type's `description` directly, is therefore discouraged.

Answer (score 38):

[Relevant Apple Swift Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printable.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH11-SW1)

Apple provides this example:

```
struct MyType: Printable {
    var name = "Untitled"
    var description: String {
        return "MyType: \(name)"
    }
}

let value = MyType()
println("Created a \(value)")
// prints "Created a MyType: Untitled"
```

If you try this in playground, you will get the same issue that you're getting (`V11lldb_expr...`). In playground, you get the description on the right hand side when you call the initializer, but the `println` doesn't return something legible.

Out of playground, however, this code behaves as you would expect. Both your code and the sample code from Apple above print the correct `description` when used in a non-playground context.

I don't think you can change this behavior in playground. It could also just be a bug.

**EDIT**: I'm pretty sure that this is a bug; I submitted a bug report to Apple.

**UPDATE**: In Swift 2, instead of `Printable`, use `CustomStringConvertible` ([relevant doc link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CustomStringConvertible_Protocol/index.html)).

```
struct MyType: CustomStringConvertible {
    var name = "Untitled"
    var description: String {
        return "MyType: \(name)"
    }
}

let value = MyType()
println("Created a \(value)")
// prints "Created a MyType: Untitled"
```

Answer (score 3):

for swift 5 just implement `CustomStringConvertible` (pls see  developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible )

Comment: Corrected link is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible/

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in the playground. If you actually compile and run the programme normally it prints:

```
(10, 20)
(10, 20)
(10, 20)
(10, 20)
```

as expected.

You should report this at https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

`AppCode` provides a `Generate| debugDescription` and ``Generate| description` . Beats typing them out for a struct with many members.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative in Swift 5+ you can extend the String.StringInterpolation

```
struct Point {
    var x : Int
    var y : Int
}

extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: Point) {
        appendInterpolation("\(value.x):\(value.y)")
    }
}
```

This will change the value for 
`print("\(p)")`
but **not** for `print(p)` - which will still use the description

Answer (score 0):

If you open the console view :
 View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor
you can see expected print lines
Checked in xCode 6.3.2 with Yosimite 10.10

[image]