# Adding or subtracting within a for loop in Swift

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop, count

I'm very new to Swift and trying to figure out how to count up within a for loop. For example, why doesn't something like this work? I want it to print the new age +1 12 times over......

So ultimately it would read:
I am now 36 years old
I am now 37 years old
etc...

```
var myAge = 35

for _ in 1...20{
    print("I am now \(myAge += 1) years old")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift does not support the syntax `myAge += 1` inside string interpolation. You can do `myAge++` instead.

```
var myAge = 35

for _ in 1...20 {
    print("I am now \(myAge++) years old")
}
```

Comment: Note that this will no longer work once Swift 3 is released. The ++ and -- operators have been deprecated. You can now do `myAge += 1` on its own line inside the for loop, then print out `myAge` inside the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

String interpolation attempts to describe a value, not evaluate an expression. Technically, it interpolates the result of calling `.description` - a `String` - on anything that conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`. See [How can I change the textual representation displayed for a type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068506/how-can-i-change-the-textual-representation-displayed-for-a-type-in-swift)

So, considering it as a value, rather than an expression, what type do you expect `myAge += 1` to be? If you add it explicitly, thus:

```
var myAge = 35

for _ in 1...20 {
    let x = (myAge += 1)
    print("I am now \(x) years old")
}
```

you will see that the compiler warns you :

"Constant x inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected."

Answer (score 0):

The code below works, apparently the print() constructor doesn't support +=, but you can update the value and then print your results.

```
var myAge = 35

for _ in 1...20{

    myAge += 1
    print("I am now \(myAge) years old")
}
```