# Swift equivalent of Java toString()

Tags: ios, swift, string, tostring, customstringconvertible

What is the Swift equivalent of Java `toString()` to print the state of a class instance?

Comment: More info @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068506/how-can-i-change-the-textual-representation-displayed-for-a-type-in-swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the textual representation displayed for a type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068506/how-can-i-change-the-textual-representation-displayed-for-a-type-in-swift)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The `description` property is what you are looking for.  This is the property that is accessed when you print a variable containing an object.

You can add `description` to your own classes by adopting the protocol `CustomStringConvertible` and then implementing the `description` property.

```
class MyClass: CustomStringConvertible {
    var val = 17

    public var description: String { return "MyClass: \(val)" }
}

let myobj = MyClass()
myobj.val = 12
print(myobj)  // "MyClass: 12"
```

`description` is also used when you call the `String` constructor:

```
let str = String(myobj)  // str == "MyClass: 12"
```

This is the recommended method for accessing the instance description (as opposed to `myobj.description` which will not work if a class doesn't implement `CustomStringConvertible`)

Comment: What about `String(obj)`?

Comment: There's also `.debugDescription` for a more programmer-friendly version

Comment: does it apply for structures?

Comment: I am following a tutorial of swift 2. They mentioned that `Printable` was the protocol to be used instead of `CustomStringConvertible `. `Printable` protocol was changed to `CustomStringConvertible ` in swift 3?

Comment: Yes, CustomStringConvertible replaced Printable.  @Antonio, I don't remember when it changed, but it was certainly long before Swift 3.

Comment: @Antonio, according to this article, the change happened at Swift 2. https://www.raywenderlich.com/108522/whats-new-in-swift-2

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd prefer Printable, I think it's a meaningful name

Comment: the MyClass must be extended from NSObject

Comment: Is there a quick way to get a `description` for a `struct` with many attributes?  `jvm` type languages tend to use reflection for this.

Comment: @javadba, For a `struct`, if you print it `print(myStruct)` or use string interpolation `"\(myStruct)"`, you'll get a default value that might be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: oh yea - I forgot that approach  `let strOut = "\(myStruct)"`    In the meantime I used `AppCode` to `Generate` the `description`

Answer (score 9):

If it is possible to use the struct instead of class, then nothing additional to do.

struct just prints fine itself to the output

```
print("\(yourStructInstance)")
```

or with class like this:

```
print(String(describing: yourClassInstance))
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `String(obj)`.

Direct from [the documentation for CustomStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CustomStringConvertible_Protocol/index.html):

> NOTE
>
> String(instance) will work for an instance of any type, returning its
>   description if the instance happens to be CustomStringConvertible.
>   Using CustomStringConvertible as a generic constraint, or accessing a
>   conforming type's description directly, is therefore discouraged.

Comment: Seems like the `description()` method of `CustomStringConvertible` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

## How it's done with `NSObject` extended classes

If your model class is extended from `NSObject`, you have to override the Variable `description` as follows:

```
public override var description: String {
    return "\n{\n index: \(self.index),\n"
        + " country: \(self.name),\n"
        + " isoCountryCode: \(self.isoCountryCode),\n"
        + " localeId: \(self.localeId),\n"
        + " flagImageName: \(self.flagImageName!)\n}"
}
```

You can check how I have done it [here within the `Country` class](https://github.com/randikachan/countrypicker-ios-swift/blob/53992fdeb83a88556cded29106b3988aa5aedb75/CountryPicker/CountryPicker/Classes/CountryInfo/Country.swift#L46), in the ["CountryPicker iOS Swift library"](https://github.com/randikachan/countrypicker-ios-swift).

**Or,** to make it simpler for you to understand, your class and `description` method should look like following:

```
public class MyClass: NSObject {
   public var memberAttribute = "I'm an attribute"

   public override var description: String {
       return "My Class member: \(self.memberAttribute)"
   }
}
```

**Note:**
Since you are extending your Modal class from `NSObject` it doesn't require for your class to comply with `CustomStringConvertible` class anymore, and you are overriding `description` variable from the `NSObject` class itself. Always remember, `CustomStringConvertible` is mostly the pure Swift way of achieving this.