# Data is being retrieved as project.model not as elements in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, methods

I am trying to retrieve the data elements from `DataTable` in `SQLite` database but when I retrieve the data I am getting the data as myproject.mymodelclass  where `WidgetData` is my model class and `myproject` is the the name of my project on which I am working here is the snapshot of console

`[MyProject.WidgetData, MyProject.WidgetData, MyProject.WidgetData, MyProject.WidgetData]`

But I want all the elements of `DataTable` should be printed in `ViewController` class.

**WidgetData Class**

```
import Foundation

class WidgetData {

var widgetid: Int64?
var widgetname: String = ""
var widgetdescription : String = ""
var widgetform: String = ""

var formid : Int64?
var formname : String = ""
var formdescription : String = ""
var formcategory : String = ""

init(widgetid: Int64) {
    self.widgetid = widgetid
}

init(formid: Int64) {
    self.formid = formid
}

init(widgetid: Int64, widgetname: String, widgetdescription: String, widgetform: String) {
    self.widgetid = widgetid
    self.widgetname = widgetname
    self.widgetdescription = widgetdescription
    self.widgetform = widgetform
}

init(formid: Int64, formname : String, formdescription : String, formcategory : String) {
    self.formid = formid
    self.formname = formname
    self.formdescription = formdescription
    self.formcategory = formcategory
}
}
```

**StephencelisDB class**

```
import Foundation
class WidgetData {

var widgetid: Int64?
var widgetname: String = ""
var widgetdescription : String = ""
var widgetform: String = ""

var formid : Int64?
var formname : String = ""
var formdescription : String = ""
var formcategory : String = ""

init(widgetid: Int64) {
    self.widgetid = widgetid
}

init(formid: Int64) {
    self.formid = formid
}

init(widgetid: Int64, widgetname: String, widgetdescription: String, widgetform: String) {
    self.widgetid = widgetid
    self.widgetname = widgetname
    self.widgetdescription = widgetdescription
    self.widgetform = widgetform
}

init(formid: Int64, formname : String, formdescription : String, formcategory : String) {
    self.formid = formid
    self.formname = formname
    self.formdescription = formdescription
    self.formcategory = formcategory
}
}
```

**ViewController** in which I am retrieving the values

```
    //SQLite start
var dataList = [WidgetData]()
var db: OpaquePointer?
var stmt: OpaquePointer?

var widgetnameV = String()
var widgetdescriptionV = String()
var widgetformV = String()

private var contacts = [WidgetData]()
private var selectedContact: Int?


func formDataSetup() {

    let queryString = "INSERT INTO WidgetTable (widgetname, widgetdescription, widgetform) VALUES (?,?,?)"
    //preparing the query
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    //binding the parameters
    if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, widgetnameV, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, widgetdescriptionV, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, widgetformV, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure binding name: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    //executing the query to insert values
    if sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("failure inserting hero: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

}



func readValues(){

    //first empty the list of heroes
    //   heroList.removeAll()

    //this is our select query
    let queryString = "SELECT * FROM WidgetTable"

    //

    print(dataList)

    //statement pointer
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?

    //preparing the query
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    //traversing through all the records
    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
        let widgetid = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)
        let widgetnameC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
        let widgetdescriptionC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2))
        let widgetformC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3))

        //adding values to list
        dataList.append(WidgetData(widgetid: Int64(Int(widgetid)), widgetname: String(describing: widgetnameC), widgetdescription: String(describing: widgetdescriptionC), widgetform: String(describing: widgetformC)))
        print(dataList)
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the textual representation displayed for a type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068506/how-can-i-change-the-textual-representation-displayed-for-a-type-in-swift).

Comment: @MartinR its obvious that the mentioned answer is about structs and I am not dealing with structs.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper: Adopting the CustomStringConvertible protocol by implementing the description method works for both classes and structs, there is no difference at all. – Did you try it?

Comment: @vadian updated the question and given answer kindly view here

Answer (score 0):

implement `description` var  to print the class properties

```
class WidgetData:NSObject
{
    var tripId: String
     var name: String

    init(tripId: String ,name:String)
    {
        self.tripId = tripId
        self.name = name

    } 
   override var description: String
    {

        return "\(self.tripId) \(self.name)"
    }

}
```

**Update**

Your problem is that you have more than one init , first I advice isolating the data to other class , or in description check first item in every init and use ! if all the init values are not nil

Comment: error occurred `Initializers may only be declared within a type` in init..... line

Comment: Why inherit from NSObject?

Comment: @Martin to override description

Comment: Not necessary. Have a look at the Q&A that I linked to above. Look for "CustomStringConvertible".

Comment: I know it's another option

Comment: @Sh_Khan updated your answer kindly update further how to get values instead of optionals

Comment: use ! in print statement