# Retrieving a column from SQLite to a label in cell of table view Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I am retrieving all the values of column `formname` to a `titleLabel` in a cell of a tableview, but unfortunately I am facing these two errors

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

and this

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

on these lines of below mentioned class.

[Here are other data model classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745527/data-is-being-retrieved-as-project-model-not-as-elements-in-swift-ios)

[image]

```
import UIKit
import SQLite
import SQLite3

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class ViewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent("Stephencelis.sqlite")


let forms = Table("FormTable")

var cities : [String]?
var dbd: Connection?

var heroList = [FormDatabase]()
var db : OpaquePointer?
var stmt:OpaquePointer?

var formidV = Int64()
var formnameV = String()
var formdescriptionV = String()
var formdateV = String()

@IBOutlet weak var menu: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var viewTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateStringLabelView: UILabel!



private init() {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true
        ).first!

    do {
        dbd = try Connection("\(path)/Stephencelis.sqlite3")
    } catch {
        dbd = nil
        print ("Unable to open database")
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



func readValues(){

    heroList.removeAll()

    //this is our select query
    let queryString = "SELECT * FROM AuditorTable"

    //statement pointer
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?

    //preparing the query
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    //traversing through all the records
    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
        let formidC = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)
        let formnameC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
        let formdescriptionC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2))
        let formcategoryC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3))
         let formdateC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4))

        //adding values to list
        heroList.append(FormDatabase(formid: Int64(formidC), formname: String(describing: formnameC), formdescription: String(describing: formdescriptionC), formcategory: String(describing: formcategoryC), formdate: String(describing: formdateC)))
    }
}

var numberofrowsinColumn = String()
func countValues(){

    //first empty the list of heroes
    //heroList.removeAll()

    //this is our select query
    let queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AuditorTable"

    //statement pointer
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?

    //preparing the query
    if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    //traversing through all the records
    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
        let formidC = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)
        let formnameC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
        let formdescriptionC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2))
        let formcategoryC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3))
        let formdateC = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4))
        //adding values to list
        heroList.append(FormDatabase(formid: Int64(formidC), formname: String(describing: formnameC), formdescription: String(describing: formdescriptionC), formcategory: String(describing: formcategoryC), formdate: String(describing: formdateC)))
        numberofrowsinColumn = queryString
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   // return heroList.count
    if cities == nil {
        return 0
    }
    return cities!.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = viewTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewTableViewCell") as! ViewTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel?.text = self.cities?[indexPath.row]



    cities = [String]()

    for row in (try dbd?.prepare(forms))! {

       try? cities!.append(row[0] as! String)





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error opening database")
    }


    viewTableView.delegate = self
    viewTableView.dataSource = self
    viewTableView.reloadData()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to something like:

```
let statement = try! dbd?.prepare(forms) 
for row in statement {
    if let city = row[0] as? String {
        cities?.append(city)
    }
}
```

Comment: this is showing the error at try? line Cannot subscript a value of type 'Row' with an index of type 'Int'

Comment: @Moritz I am getting an error: Cannot subscript a value of type 'Row' with an index of type 'Int'

Answer (score 0):

You are using the method:

```
func prepare(_ query: QueryType) throws -> AnySequence<Row>
```

With this method you cannot use `row[0]` you need to use the method `row.get(Expression<V>)` which seems to be the name of the column.

The method you are trying to use is:

```
public func prepare(_ statement: String, _ bindings: Binding?...) throws -> Statement
```

With this function you can use `row[0]`

To be a little bit more clear you have two possibilities.

## 1

```
let forms = Table("FormTable")
...

cities = [String]()
if let connection = dbd {
    for row in try connection.prepare(forms) {
        // I'm not entirely sure about the way to use Expression
        let columnName = Expression<String>("COLUMN_NAME")
        try cities!.append(row.get(columnName))
    }
}
```

## 2

```
cities = [String]()
if let connection = dbd {
    for row in connection.prepare("SELECT * FROM FormTable") {
        try? cities!.append(row[0] as! String)
    }
}
```

I came to this solution by reading the source code.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanx Xavier but I am getting an error from option 1 solution that at `try` line I have found this error

Comment: You should always handle the errors. You need to add a way to handle the errors for each `try` and for the `if let connection = dbd`.

Comment: same error in second solution would you do something please

Comment: does your code is open source so I can look at it to see what's wrong ? Make sure that the database exists and is not empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165406/discussion-between-xavier-bauquet-and-ios-developer).

Comment: database exists and table exists but code is here at mentioned link in question's description see the link