# Function to add annotations to a map in MapKit not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

The relevant code to create a map and add an annotation to it is here:

```
class LandmarkAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let title: String?
    let subtitle: String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
init(title: String?,
     subtitle: String?,
     coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}


struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let landmarks = LandmarkAnnotation(title: "test", subtitle: "subtest", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.786996, longitude: -122.419281))//.requestMockData()
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        MapViewCoordinator(self)
    }
    
    /**
     - Description - Replace the body with a make UIView(context:) method that creates and return an empty MKMapView
     */
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView{
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context){
        //If you changing the Map Annotation then you have to remove old Annotations
        //mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        //This doesn't add annotations for some reason
        view.addAnnotations([landmarks])
        print(landmarks)
        //print returns <River_Watch.LandmarkAnnotation: 0x282758a80> for some reason
    }
}

/*
  Coordinator for using UIKit inside SwiftUI.
 */
class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    
      var mapViewController: MapView
        
      init(_ control: MapView) {
          self.mapViewController = control
      }
        
      func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor
           annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
         //Custom View for Annotation
          let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customView")
          annotationView.canShowCallout = true
          //Your custom image icon
          annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "locationPin")
          return annotationView
       }
}
```

For some reason the variable "landmarks" isn't formatted correctly to be added as an annotation and when I printed the variable it returned `<River_Watch.LandmarkAnnotation: 0x282758a80>`which I would assume isn't the proper formatting for an annotation. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Try to call `view.addAnnotations([landmarks])` a little later, and make sure to make this call in the main thread.

Comment: Regarding `print(landmarks)`, variable `landmarks` is a `LandmarkAnnotation` object located at memory address 0x282758a80 in this particular instance.  Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068506/how-can-i-change-the-textual-representation-displayed-for-a-type-in-swift to understand how to make your `LandmarkAnnotation` object print itself "nicely".

Comment: Create an `MKMarkerAnnotationView` instead of `let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customView")`

Comment: what happens if you force unwrap the UIImage(named: "locationPin")

Comment: Take a look how to handle your reuseidentifier: https://www.raywenderlich.com/7738344-mapkit-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-009

Comment: With all I said, `MKMarkerAnnotationView` could be the most important.