# How do I fix the print statement to where it only shows the first person in the collection and so it looks neat and doesn't show all the nonsense

Tags: swift, struct, func

I am trying to print a list of people with their names and their height in order from tallest to shortest. When I do that there is a lot of unnecessary text in the print box. Another problem. I have is when I try to print tallest.first it prints all of the values inside instead of just the first one. I am going to put in the entire code so you can see the full picture.

```
struct PersonHeight {
    let name: String
    let height: Int
    var formattedHeight: String {
        return "\(height / 12)'\(height % 12)"
    }
}
let James = PersonHeight(name: "James", height: 50)
let Sam = PersonHeight(name: "Sam", height: 60)
let Dude = PersonHeight(name: "Dude", height: 55)
let array = [James, Sam, Dude]

func personHeight(people: [PersonHeight]) {
    var personCount = 0
    let shortest = [people.sorted{ $0.height < $1.height}]
    let tallest = [people.sorted{ $0.height > $1.height}]

    for person in people {
        personCount += 1
    }
    print("There are \(personCount) people and here are their names:")
    for person in tallest {
        print("\(person).")
    }
             print("The shortest person is \(shortest.first!) and the tallest person is \(tallest.first!)")
}

personHeight(people: array)
```

I have tried a few different things and none of them worked. One thing was setting it to a let or variable and it is not working. I also tried just straight sorting it but I got an error for that aswell.

Comment: This is what it prints.
[__lldb_expr_23.PersonHeight(name: "Sam", height: 60), __lldb_expr_23.PersonHeight(name: "Dude", height: 55), __lldb_expr_23.PersonHeight(name: "James", height: 50)].
The shortest person is [__lldb_expr_23.PersonHeight(name: "James", height: 50), __lldb_expr_23.PersonHeight(name: "Dude", height: 55), __lldb_expr_23.PersonHeight(name: "Sam", height: 60)] and the tallest person is [__lldb_expr_23.PersonHeight(name: "Sam", height: 60), __lldb_expr_23.PersonHeight(name: "Dude", height: 55), __lldb_expr_23.PersonHeight(name: "James", height: 50)]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the textual representation displayed for a type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068506/how-can-i-change-the-textual-representation-displayed-for-a-type-in-swift)

Comment: Usually, this "strange prefiix" output is seen in Playground. When you do `"\(person)"`, you call in fact `description`, and it's the default one. Make your struct conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` to have your own custom `description`.